# Make div "window" into another div below

Tags: html, css, css-position

To make a scroll-like animation with css i would like to have one html div as a "window" giving sight onto another div, the latter of which I could later animate to move up and down, cutting off the content as it slides out of the viewport. The background div is supposed to contain text only, in different lines, the front or "window" div does not contain anything but has the height of only one line of text.

Most answers link to the option of specifying the parent element as "position: relative;" while the child inside is "absolute;". However, as soon as I start moving the latter then it slides out of the vieport. Overflow:hidden; does not work for the window div for some reason.

```
<div class="sometext">
hello I am 
  <div class="window">
    funny
    <div class="view">
    funny<br>great<br>dull<br>silly
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sometext{
  background-color:pink;
}

.window{
  display:inline;
  position:relative;
  color:transparent;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:green;
  z-index:1;
}

.view{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 color:black;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

see:
https://jsfiddle.net/u23hv1dx/

Note:

- The viewport should be only the green rectangle thus initially only showing the word "funny", which should be possible to change by manipulating the .view top parameter
- The .window element contains the (transparent) word "funny" for the sole reason to have the necessary width of the chil
- Btw, why is the child here positioned slightly to right of the ancestor?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood correctly your question.
You cannot set overflow hidden to inline elements.
Use inline-block, then vertical-align the content to bottom and set a line-height: 1. It should fix it.